# What is the purpose of -1 at the end of an if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Having the following code which gets as input a JSON of this format:

```
{
  "143334": ["VW", "Golf", "Diesel or Gas", "Affordable", "Blue, red or white"],
  "344389": ["VW", "Passat", "Diesel or Gas", "More expensive"],
  "484612": ["Audi", "A8", "Diesel", "Premium"],
  "234234": ["Renault", "Megane", "not too much info"]
}
```

and returns it grouped by brand and sorts it alphabetically by brand and model:

```
[
  {
    "brand": "Audi",
    "models": [
      {
        "model": "A8",
        "id": "484612",
        "characteristics": ["Diesel", "Premium"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "brand": "Renault",
    "models": [
      {
        "model": "Megane",
        "id": "234234",
        "characteristics": ["not too much info"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "brand": "VW",
    "models": [
      {
        "model": "Golf",
        "id": "143334",
        "characteristics": ["Diesel or Gas", "Affordable", "Blue, red or white"]
      },
      {
        "model": "Passat",
        "id": "344389",
        "characteristics": ["Diesel or Gas", "More expensive"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The implementation works well, it was answered in a different question:

```
function doMagic(json) {
  let res = [];
  let arr = JSON.parse(json)
  Object.keys(arr).forEach(k => {
    let tempIndex = res.findIndex(r => r.brand === arr[k][0])
    if(-1 === tempIndex) { // if the brand isn't in the array yet
      tempIndex = res.push({
        brand:arr[k][0],
        models:[]
      })-1
    }
    res[tempIndex].models.push({
        "model": arr[k][1],
        "id": k,
        "characteristics": arr[k].slice(2)
      })
  })
  res.sort((a,b) => a.brand.localeCompare(b.brand))
  res.forEach(e => e.models.sort((a,b) => a.model.localeCompare(b.model)))
  return res
 }
```

I'm trying to understand what is happening here:

```
if(-1 === tempIndex) {
  tempIndex = res.push({
    brand:arr[k][0],
    models:[]
  })-1 // what does this do?
}
```

What's the purpose of that `-1` after pushing an element into the array?

Comment: `.push` returns the new length, when doing `-1` `tempIndex` will be length of array minus one, which means the last index.

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN article on [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) (emphasis mine):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

`push` returns the length of the array, so the statement is simply returning the index of the last element added (by subtracting 1 from the length). It might be easier to read like this:

```
tempIndex = res.push({...}) - 1;
```

---

Simplified demo:

```js
var arr = ["first", "second", "third"];
var totalLength = arr.push("fourth");
var tempIndex = totalLength - 1;
console.log(`Array length: ${totalLength}, Last item: ${arr[tempIndex]}`);
```